# How can I make CircuitMaker generate gerber files for 2 PCB's

Tags: gerber, circuitmaker

Right now I have 2 schematics and 2 PCBs in one project in Circuit Maker. When I generate Gerber output files for the project, it only does the PCB that I first created. Is there a way to have it generate the second PCB?

[image: Directory of my Project]